# Cannot create ODATA feed in Microsoft Excel

Tags: acumatica

This error message pops out when I try to create Odata feed from Excel see attached image. Anybody knows the possible reason and how can we create it from Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Acumatica do you use?

Please try to access your OData feed from a web browser.

Comment: I'm using Acumatica version 5.30.1966, how can I access it through web browser?

Comment: Hi Sophak, I tried that and it just gives me this XML error, "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it."

Comment: What screen that you attached the image to?

Comment: Thanks, Sophak, It is working in browser now but still can't work in excel.

Comment: I mean for example: I attached image on Employee screen and then I created generic inquiry to get the attached image right?